# Link from tags to tag pages displaying all posts with that tag

Tags: tags

`<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->id); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>`

I was using this to try to list the first tag for a post, and make it so that when you click on that tag you go to a page which lists all of the posts with that tag. Instead, when you click the link it just refreshes the page. I tried going directly to one of our tag pages and it exists but it's totally empty.

How do I get each tag to link to it's tag page and how do I populate tag pages with posts?

Answer (score 3):

you haven't shown in your code how you get `$tag`, therefore I include my version (the code has to be in the loop):

```
<?php $tags = get_the_tags(); 
if( $tags ) foreach( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>
<?php break; } ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags